# Nested query into view?

Tags: sql

Im trying to figure out the correct syntax to have a nested query for MS Sql, I am hoping to take the values from one column from another then convert the result into an absolute value and then insert into a view. How do I go about doing this?

```
     CREATE VIEW -- select * from 
    [Product_Revenue]
      AS
   SELECT Name,[REV_Accounted_Debit]-[REV_Accounted_Credit] as [diff]
   select abs[diff] as Amount from SalesListing
    FROM [SalesListing]
```

Comment: You don't really insert into views.  Think of views as a select statement that you can run selects on.  You would insert the value into the table the view is being created from.  Kinda confused what you are trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no need for recursivity on this.

```
CREATE VIEW -- select * from 
Product_Revenue
  AS
SELECT Name, 
       REV_Accounted_Debit]-[REV_Accounted_Credit as diff,
       abs(REV_Accounted_Debit-REV_Accounted_Credit) as Amount
FROM SalesListing
```